# Backbone Relational - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, undefined, marionette, backbone-relational

I have a BackboneRelational model defined in a file:

```
define(function (require) {
var Backbone = require('backbone'),
    BackboneRelational = require('backbone.relational'),
    StudentDetails = require('./StudentDetails');

var Classroom = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    url : "../server/student-records.json",
    relations : [{
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: 'studentDetails',
        relatedModel: StudentDetails,
        collectionType: Backbone.Collection,
        fetchRelated: false
    }]
});

return Classroom;
});
```

I am using this model in another file like this:

```
define(function(require) {
    var Marionette = require('marionette'),
        Classroom = require('../model/Classroom');

    var ClassroomController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
        initialize: function(args){
            this.mainRegion = args;

            var jsondata = new Classroom();

            jsondata.fetch({
                success:function(){
                    console.log(jsondata);
                    ......................
                    ....some code here....
                    ......................
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return ClassroomController;
});
```

I am gettin **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** error at line:

```
var jsondata = new Classroom();
```

Can anybody point out where am i going wrong?

Comment: There is no glaringly obvious bug in your code. We need more info about your error if you want help. What function is undefined? I'm guessing it's not `Classroom`. So what is it?

Answer (score 2):

This may be because you didn't specify extension from RelationalModel for every single model that is used in relations. Once a model is used in relation you actually MUST extend it by RelationalModel. Hope that helps

Comment: I was getting `TypeError: this.set is not a function` when initiating my models and could not find out why. Turns out the last model in a quite long relation chain did not extend Backbone.RelationalModel. *Pewt!* This saved me from a lot of desperate debugging.